# Adding Offsets to My Java Game

Tags: java, scroll

So, as the title reads I am trying to add offsets to my java game. I was given a tip by a friend that I need to minus the offset from where I render the tiles onto my screen.

So I created a random world generator and did the offset thing, but I ran into a problem.

My Code:

```
public void generateMap(Graphics g) {

        block = seed.nextInt(2);

        //Render Dirt
        if(block == 0) {
            g.drawImage(Assets.dirt, x - GameState.xOffset, y - GameState.yOffset, null);

            x += 32;
        }

        //Render Grass
        if(block == 1) {
            g.drawImage(Assets.grass, x - GameState.xOffset, y - GameState.yOffset, null);

            x += 32;
        }

        //Check Where the X is
        if(x > xFinish) {
            if(y < yFinish) {
                x = xStart;
                y += 32;
            }
        }
    }
```

looks simple enough right? after I do that I create code to add one to the offset every time I loop around:

```
public void tick() {
    xOffset += 1;
    }
```

So after that is done I run it but it does this:

[image: example of issue]

is there any simple way I can fix this so that it appears that the screen "scrolls" to the left?

Comment: Do you have some information (name would be good) about the API your using for types like `Assets`, `GameState`? Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve - a scrolling effect no matter what else is going on? Something different?

Comment: There is nothing really to say, the Assets just stores the bufferedimage pictures so I do not have to load them every time. And the GameState class has the tick method and calls the generateMap method about 60 times a second. And I am trying to be able to navigate around my map and still keep the player in one place, hope that makes sense.

Comment: Is it not scrolling, or scrolling but producing the effect in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any simple way I can fix this...**

Probably not. Games are complicated. Don't let that dissuade you.

You are generating your game world and drawing in the same methods - you don't want to do this. [Separation of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is very important - you don't want a whole bunch of code in one spot doing the same thing. In this case, the functionality to generate the world and the drawing code need to be split.

For the world generation, generate the game world once, and persist it to storage using whatever format you like. *Keep this away from the drawing code* - it has no place there.

For representing blocks in your world, consider something like this:

```
class Block { 
    public BlockType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getxPosition() {
        return xPosition;
    }

    public int getyPosition() {
        return yPosition;
    }

    // hashCode(), equals(), etc omitted, they should be implemented

    public static enum BlockType { 
        Dirt(Assets.dirt), 
        Grass(Assets.grass); 

        private final BufferedImage image; 

        BlockType(BufferedImage image) { 
            this.image = image; 
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage() {
            return image; 
        }
    }

    private final BlockType type; 
    private final int xPosition; 
    private final int yPosition; 

    private Block(BlockType type, int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        this.type = type; 
        this.xPosition = xPosition; 
        this.yPosition = yPosition; 
    } 

    public static Block getInstance(BlockType type, int xPosition, int yPosition) { 
        return new Block(type, xPosition, yPosition);
    }
}
```

You can then use `Block.getInstance()` to generate a map *once*, like this:

```
class GameState { 
    private final int WORLD_SIZE = 1024; 
    private Block[][] _world = new Block[WORLD_SIZE][WORLD_SIZE]; 
    private static Random seed = new Random(); 

    public void generateMap() { 
        int blockTypeLength = Block.BlockType.values().length;
        for (int x = 0; x < WORLD_SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < WORLD_SIZE; y++) { 
                int blockType = seed.nextInt(blockTypeLength);
                _world[x][y] = Block.getInstance(Block.BlockType.values()[blockType], x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    public Block[][] getMap() {
        return _world; // not thread safe, shares internal state, all the usual warnings
    }
```

This obviously isn't the only way to generate a world - you would probably generate a world and save, then load from disk in later games (unless it was a short lived game - I don't know, that's your call).

Once you've got the world sorted out, you'd move on to a different module that would handle drawing. Assume GameState has two fields `playerX` and `playerY` that represent the player's coordinates in the game world (note: direct fields like this are bad practice, but used to simplify this example):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    Block[][] screen = new Block[16][16]; // declare a screen buffer to draw
    // Assumes player is in the center of the screen
    int screenRadiusX = GameFrame.Assets.SCREENBOUNDS_X / 2 / blockSize;
    int screenRadiusY = GameFrame.Assets.SCREENBOUNDS_Y / 2 / blockSize;
    for (int x = state.playerX - 8, xS = 0; x < state.playerX + 8; x++, xS++) {
        for (int y = state.playerY - 8, yS = 0; y < state.playerY + 8; y++, yS++) { 
            screen[xS][yS] = world[x][y]; 
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < screen.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < screen.length; y++) { 
            Block current = screen[x][y];
            g.drawImage(current.getType().getImage(), 
                    x * blockSize, // blockSize is the pixel dimension of 
                    y * blockSize,
                    null
            );
        }
    }
}
```

If this helps, then great! I'm glad I was able to help. If not, or if some ideas are still unclear, then I would consider perhaps running through a tutorial or book that walks you through making a game. Don't forget to learn the platform you're coding on during such a process.

Comment: I just have one last problem, IF I wanted to make infinate world generation (With Chunks like in the game minecraft) how would I do that? Because in your code it generates the world once and thats it.